# Polars: how to handle 'window expression not allowed in aggregation'?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a task on hand where I want to perform regressions of transformed columns on a set of specified columns in a polars dataframe. The transformation and set of independent columns are all controlled by a `specs` dict.

Below is a simplified mini example for illustrating purposes.

```
from functools import partial

import polars as pl
import numpy as np


def ols_fitted(s: pl.Series, yvar: str, xvars: list[str]) -> pl.Series:
    df = s.struct.unnest()
    y = df[yvar].to_numpy()
    X = df[xvars].to_numpy()
    fitted = np.dot(X, np.linalg.lstsq(X, y, rcond=None)[0])
    return pl.Series(values=fitted, nan_to_null=True)


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "g1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "g2": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        "g3": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
        "x1": [2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2],
        "x2": [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "x3": [3, 6, 8, 6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 8, 1],
    }
)

specs = {
    "first": {"yvar": "y", "gvars": ["g1"], "xvars": ["x1"]},
    "second": {"yvar": "y", "gvars": ["g1", "g2"], "xvars": ["x1", "x2"]},
    "third": {"yvar": "y", "gvars": ["g2", "g3"], "xvars": ["x2", "x3"]},
}

df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.struct(
            [
                (
                    pl.col(specs[specnm]["yvar"])
                    - pl.col(specs[specnm]["yvar"]).mean().over(specs[specnm]["gvars"])
                ).abs(),
                *specs[specnm]["xvars"],
            ]
        )
        .apply(
            partial(
                ols_fitted, yvar=specs[specnm]["yvar"], xvars=specs[specnm]["xvars"]
            )
        )
        .over(["date", "id"])
        .alias(f"fitted_{specnm}")
        for specnm in list(specs.keys())
    ]
)
```

However, I got the error below:

```
exceptions.InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation
```

Not sure why over is not supported within aggregation context. Would be very convenient if it does like in my example.

So, my real question is how to handle this in my particular case? And, if it cannot be handled, is there any alternative ways to make my code work in a systematic way?

Comment: I think the list comprehension does not add anything useful but complexity to the question. You get the same error if you hard code one key/value pair. Feel free to open a feature request on Github, I'm sure @ritchie46 will know best how to handle this. Maybe there's a fundamental reason window expressions aren't allowed in aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When you can't use windows functions (`over`) you just have to be explicit and do a `groupby`, `apply` and `explode` by foot:

```py
df.lazy().with_columns(
    [
        pl.struct(
            [
                (
                    pl.col(specs[specnm]["yvar"])
                    - pl.col(specs[specnm]["yvar"])
                    .mean()
                    .over(specs[specnm]["gvars"])
                ).abs(),
                *specs[specnm]["xvars"],
            ]
        ).alias(f"pre_{specnm}")
        for specnm in list(specs.keys())
    ]
).groupby(["date", "id"], maintain_order=True).agg(
    [
        *[
            pl.col(f"pre_{specnm}").apply(
                partial(
                    ols_fitted,
                    yvar=specs[specnm]["yvar"],
                    xvars=specs[specnm]["xvars"],
                )
            )
            for specnm in list(specs.keys())
        ],
        pl.exclude([f"pre_{specnm}" for specnm in list(specs.keys())]),
    ]
).explode(
    pl.exclude(["date", "id"])
).collect()
```

Note that I made it lazy, in line with best practices.

Comment: Do we need ```maintain_order=True``` here? Also, what does ```pl.exclude```?

Comment: Possibly don't need `maintain_order`. `pl.exclude`: _Syntactic sugar for pl.all().exclude(columns)_, see https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.exclude.html

Comment: Got it. Without ```maintain_order=True```, relative orders for columns in aggregation context should be maintained, right?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the solution: since we moved ```over``` outside, we also need to expand the ```over``` to include ```date``` and ```id``` as well.

Comment: It depends what you want - one could add add them to the `over` after `mean()`